# Vagrant Up Error: VBoxManage.exe: error: The VM session was closed before any attempt to power it on

Tags: windows, vagrant, virtualbox

I am using Vagrant to setup a C++ Dev Environment on Windows. I successfully installed and started my virtual machine; halting and rebooting the VM also yielded no errors. However this time executing "vagrant up" shows:

```
Bringing machine 'default' up with 'virtualbox' provider...
==> default: Checking if box 'bento/ubuntu-20.10' version '202107.07.0' is up to date...
==> default: Clearing any previously set forwarded ports...
==> default: Clearing any previously set network interfaces...
==> default: Preparing network interfaces based on configuration...
    default: Adapter 1: nat
==> default: Forwarding ports...
    default: 22 (guest) => 2222 (host) (adapter 1)
==> default: Running 'pre-boot' VM customizations...
==> default: Booting VM...
There was an error while executing `VBoxManage`, a CLI used by Vagrant
for controlling VirtualBox. The command and stderr is shown below.

Command: ["startvm", "dd8f5b68-3401-4bdd-aaa5-a1ce346ac9d9", "--type", "headless"]

Stderr: VBoxManage.exe: error: The VM session was closed before any attempt to power it on
VBoxManage.exe: error: Details: code E_FAIL (0x80004005), component SessionMachine, interface ISession
```

I tried to discard the saved state of my VM in the VirtualBox GUI, but the error is still here. What can I do?

Comment: This question is off topic for Stack Overflow. The issue is with Virtualbox, not vagrant. I would recommend asking on [Super User](https://superuser.com).

Comment: Well, I have fixed the issue by Destroying vagrant with vagrant destroy and then deleted homestead folder from C:\Users\USERNAME\VirtualBox VMs and then running vagrant up. It will recreate that.